Airflow pods wil only run on one k8s node (probably not an affinity issue)
I am running Airflow (deployed via Helm chart) using the KubernetesExecutor on a microk8s cluster that's also runnig Ceph.
We have 4 nodes. A control node and three identical data/processing nodes.
I have set proper affinity and resource limits for all relevant pods and confirmed that they are displaying correctly in the cluster. So if this is an affinity issue, it's not a basic affinity issue.
All processing pods will only get scheduled on one specific node. If it is not available, they will not be scheduled. Later I found out that this applies to all Airflow bods, not just processing pods. That is, all processing pods will only run on data03, but the Airflow postgres pod will only be scheduled on data02. They won't get scheduled on other nodes even if their original nodes are down.
If I spawn too many processing pods, I get
0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) insufficient cpou. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling, 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.


data03 is indeed fully subscribed, but the other two are basically idle and free to handle multiple pods.
If I cordon data03, then no processing pods are scheduled and I get

0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling, 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.

It's trying to preempt even though there's absoulutely no preemption necessary. All three pods look like this and are opreating perfectly for Ceph.
Capacity:
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  256920004Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             32589584Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  255871428Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             32487184Ki
  pods:               110

I've played around with various affinities, antiAffinities and resource limits, but something seems to be limiting Airflow pods to single nodes and I can't see what it might be.
